# Cannot access props on Socket Phoenix with React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, sockets, redux, apache-phoenix

Im trying to add socket funcionality to a component I have. The problem is that when I receive a message Iḿ not able to acces the component props in order to call the actionCreators I need to call.

```
class Navbar extends React.Component<NavbarType> {
 const {updateSyncSubmissions} = this.props.updateSyncSubmissions;
  componentWillMount() {
    let socket = new Socket ( 'ws:localhost:4000/socket' ,
      { transport: websocket.w3cwebsocket } );
    socket.connect();
    socket.onOpen(function(){
      console.log("connection open");
    });
    let channelName = "notification_room:"+this.props.userId;
    let channel = socket.channel(channelName,{});
    channel.join()
      .receive("ok", function (resp) {
          console.log("CONNECTED TO CHANNEL ");
          console.log(resp);
      });
    channel.on("notification:msg", function(resp) {
      console.log("RECIEVED");
      console.log(resp);
    });

    channel.on("notification:sync", (resp) =>{
      console.log("SYNCCCCCC", this);
      updateSyncSubmissions(resp.msj.percentage, resp.msj.is_done);
      console.log(resp);
    });

  }

}
```

On the above code I cannot access the `updateSyncSubmissions` inside the funcion for the `on("notification:sync")`, because 'this' it is on another scope.

Is there any way I can dispatch my actions when I receive a new message via socket on my component?